# using PlayerPrefs vs staticVariable in unity

Tags: optimization, unity-game-engine, static-classes

I am using static class with handful of static variables to save properties like 'currentPlayer' , 'currentLevel', 'currentScore' etc through out the game.
These are called very often throughout entire game flow. But not often as per frame.
Over all this class is referenced for more then a 100 times at different points as well as multiple times at same location. 
I want to know if this is a fine approach or should I use PlayerPrefs, or there may be another good approach?
Just to mention these variables are temporary and doesn't need to be saved but needs to be saved going back and forth in different game scenes.
Game is for mobiles with target of 512 MB RAM and low processor.
TIA

Comment: That sounds fine.  PlayerPrefs is not the same thing; that is used to load/save such values.  Using a singleton pattern is a bit conventional, but I don't think it's the end of the world.

Answer (score 1):

If those variables are values that needs to be saved such as player scores, player settings such as volume, level then use `PlayerPrefs`.Using `PlayerPrefs` is like killing two birds with one stone. If you use `static` variable to hold such values, you will still need to save those values at some point with `PlayerPrefs`, which means that you are now using both `static` variable and `PlayerPrefs`.

If those variables are values that does not need to be saved, use a `static` variable.

Answer (score 1):

It's worth elaborating a bit on Programmer's response that static, or class, variables persist throughout the session. As objects of the class are removed, or the scene changes, you will still have access to these values.  PlayerPrefs is like the next level, that actually writes to a non-volatile location on the device.

Answer (score 0):

I think the Unity approach is to use 'Scriptable Objects' if you don't want to save this data. you can set those variables in editor and then use them in game or change them in game.